# Issue with child scoping of this in Typescript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, this, typescript, scoping

This is *ALMOST* the same as every other `this` scoping question I have read so far other than one slight difference which makes it relevant (imo) to ask this question.

Now originally my problem was scoping of `this` with Knockout and Typescript, so given the following:

```
class ViewModel
{
    public SomeObservableArray = new ko.observableArray();

    public AddToTheObservableArray(someJsonData: any) 
    {
        this.SomeObservableArray.push(new SomePojo(someJsonData));
    }
}
```

So the `this` bit in the above code would blow up because Typescript makes you think that `this` is the class instance, but in reality it is some other this because of an ajax callback or view element, whatever the scenario that overrides the `this` keyword.

So to fix that, most solutions are to move that code into the constructor for the class, which I personally find horrible, however this small amount of horror is acceptable given the other benefits I get from using TypeScript. So just so we are all on the same page, the code below fixes the above problem:

```
class ViewModel
{
    public SomeObservableArray = new ko.observableArray();
    public AddToTheObservableArray = (someJsonData: any) => Void;

    constructor
    {
        this.AddToTheObservableArray = (someJsonData: any) => {
            this.SomeObservableArray.push(new SomePojo(someJsonData));
        };
    }
}
```

I am just writing this example code off top of my head so I apologize for any typos etc, but it hilights the common issue faced and the common solution/work around.

**NOW!** the issue I have is the next step from here, I have code like so:

```
class ViewModel
{
    public SomeObservableArray = new ko.observableArray();
    public AddToTheObservableArray = (someJsonData: any) => Void;


    constructor
    {
        this.PopulateObservableArray = (someJsonArrayData: any) => {
            this.SomeObservableArray.removeAll();
            someJsonArrayData.forEach(function(someJsonData) {
                this.SomeObservableArray.push(new SomePojo(someJsonData));
            });
        };
    }
}
```

The outputted code looks like so:

```
var ViewModel = (function(){
    function ViewModel(){
        var _this = this;

        this.SomeObservableArray = new ko.observableArray();

        this.AddMultipleEntitiesToObservableArray = function(someJsonArrayData) {
            _this.SomeObservableArray.removeAll();
            someJsonArrayData.forEach(function(someJsonData) {
                this.SomeObservableArray.push(new SomePojo(someJsonData));
            });
        }
    };
    return ViewModel;
})();
```

Again I apologise for any typos as I am just simplifying the larger projects output, however the main thing to see here is that the forEach methods child `this` remains, so I get the error `this.SomeObservableArray is undefined`.

I am sure 1 possible solution is to extract the foreach out and make it its own method, however this then feels like sticking cellotape over blutack, so I was wondering if there is some more elegant solution or some wrongdoing on my part which can be changed to at least not have to make it more unreadable.

Comment: I did a video tutorial on the subject of `this` in TypeScript https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is, and it's actually pretty easy. Just use the lambda expression on **any** method you want to get scoped to the scope of the higher function. In your case you need to rewrite your example as:

```
class ViewModel
{
    public SomeObservableArray = new ko.observableArray();
    public AddToTheObservableArray = (someJsonData: any) => Void;


    constructor()
    {
        this.PopulateObservableArray = (someJsonArrayData: any) => {
            this.SomeObservableArray.removeAll();
            someJsonArrayData.forEach((someJsonData) => {
                this.SomeObservableArray.push(new SomePojo(someJsonData));
            });
        };
    }
}
```

*PS: it's considered a best practice not to manipulate an observable array in a for each, as the subscribers of that array will be notified on each change. Just push your data to a temporary array and then set this array as the value of your observable array (just my 2cts.)*

Comment: I completely agree with your P.S, was just making this example up as I was going. If anything your solution makes the current code more elegant, so you sir are my hero!